# How to create SQL procedure with string concatination?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have tried this procedure to insert data:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE myproc()
BEGIN
    DECLARE i int DEFAULT 30;
    DECLARE acc = 'access';
    WHILE i <= 80 DO
        acc = acc + i + '@gmail.com';
        INSERT INTO users (email, status, password) VALUES (acc, 1, '$2y$12$/Jc6ayqwr333Od/0bexYF.aT1h34mzmElG8SFozzrWjhokS6wEUA6');
        SET i = i + 1;
    END WHILE;
END
```

But problem is in line: `acc = acc + i + '@gmail.com';`

How to do that right in MySQL?

Also I have tried this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE myproc()
BEGIN
    DECLARE i INT;
    DECLARE acc VARCHAR;
    i = 16;
    WHILE i <= 17 DO
        acc = 'access' + i + '@gmail.com';
        INSERT INTO users (email, status, password) VALUES (acc, 1, '$2y$12$/Jc6ayqwr333Od/0bexYF.aT1h34mzmElG8SFozzrWjhokS6wEUA6');
        SET i = i + 1;
    END WHILE;
END
```

Comment: Problem in line `  DECLARE i int DEFAULT 30;`

Comment: + is an arithmetic operator in mysql use concat imstead.

Comment: Use dot instead + ?

Comment: Dot is not a string concatenation function. Can you give an example of what you want acc to look like for first iteration.

Comment: In result I want to add value as 'access2@gmail.com' and accessN@gmail.com where N is value of variable i

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not declared the type for acc and have not used a set clause to set it in the loop and you don't know how to concat in mysql and the concat you are attempting is logically wrong.

try this

```
drop procedure if exists p;

delimiter $$
CREATE PROCEDURE p()
BEGIN
    DECLARE i int DEFAULT 30;
    DECLARE acc varchar(10) default 'access';
    declare vemail varchar(30);
    WHILE i <= 35 DO
        set vemail = concat(acc,i,'@gmail.com');
        #INSERT INTO users (email, status, password) VALUES (vemail, 1, '$2y$12$/Jc6ayqwr333Od/0bexYF.aT1h34mzmElG8SFozzrWjhokS6wEUA6');
        select vEmail;
        SET i = i + 1;
    END WHILE;
END $$
delimiter ;

call p()
```

When you are happy with the vemail format uncomment the insert and remove the select

Comment: erro on line `delimiter $$` unexpected symbol $

Comment: Where are you creating this procedure (mysqlworkbench,phpmyadmin?)

Comment: iside phpmyadmin

Comment: Then use whichever delimiter you would normally use or none if you are doing so in a wizard,

Comment: I get a new message: `Ответ MySQL: #1064 - У вас ошибка в запросе. Изучите документацию по используемой версии MySQL на предмет корректного синтаксиса около 'DECLARE i int DEFAULT 16;
    DECLARE acc varchar(10) default 'access';
    de' на строке 1`

Comment: Problem in this line: DECLARE i int DEFAULT 16;

Comment: You cannot say i = 16 see comments on set.

Comment: How to setdefault value then?

Comment: Study my answer